# Show large set of data with sorting and filtering in a Sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint, grid, web-parts

I'd like to create a Sharepoint web part to show a **large set of data from an ODBC source** (in first instance a SQL Server 2008 database) with the ability to sort and filter data, possibly with progressive fetching.

What is your advice on technology to be used?

- Report Viewer Web Part: I think it's kinda cool but will not enable progressive fetching of data
- Custom Web part with a custom GridView control embedded
- **Custom Web part with a vendor grid control embedded (Telerik, DevExpress, etc)**
- Vendor Sharepoint grid control (exists?)

Any other option available?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts

Mauro

Comment: Please specify the sharepoint version.

Comment: SP 2007, possibly moving to 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take SharePoint out of the equation. If this was a regular ASP.NET application, how would you do it? From what you have described, your custom web part is just a custom ASP.NET custom control that can be placed on the page at run time. It sounds like SharePoint is just a wrapper for your web part with no interaction necessary with SharePoint data or the API.

If in an ASP.NET application you would use SSRS for this, then use the Report Viewer Web Part. Otherwise you can use a GridView, Repeater, ListView, third party control, etc for display with Entity Framework, ADO.NET, LINQ to SQL, etc for data access. There are pros and cons with each and there is no one size fits all answer. Use whatever you are most comfortable with that makes the most sense for exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Rich. I think you are right, it was exactly the kind of thoughts we were doing on the subject. Thank you for sharing, happily our thoughts agree.

Answer (score 2):

Does the standard list view not do what you require? It sorts and filters, and has progressive fetching. I would try to get users to use that interface before duplicating it.

I have done a custom `SPGridView`. It behaves sort of like the standard list views. But it is a lot of effort to get it working correctly, especially with sorting and paging. The paging sort of ended up like this. `SPListItemCollectionPosition` is the key. In the end though, when it got upgraded to sp2010, i made the stakeholders change their requirements, so we could use the standard list views.

```
public class SPPagedGridView : SPGridView {

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {
        base.CreateChildControls();     
        AllowPaging = true;
        PageSize = PAGE_SIZE;
        PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(oGrid_PageIndexChanging);
    }

    protected override void InitializePager(GridViewRow row, int columnSpan, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) {
        pagedDataSource.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        base.InitializePager(row, columnSpan, pagedDataSource);
    }

    void oGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
        PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        DataBind();
    }

    public override DataBind() {
        SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
        q.RowLimit = PAGE_SIZE;
        SPListItemCollectionPosition pos = new SPListItemCollectionPosition(value);
        q.ListItemCollectionPosition = pos;
        //SPList list = something;
        //list.GetListItems()
    }
}
```

Comment: Question edited. Fact is, source of data is an external sql server database.

Comment: Or I can use a ListView and bind it to my datasource. Is it possible? Does it use progresive fetching also from SQL Server database?

Comment: For a external database you should have no problems then, just implement the standard asp.net paging http://varjabedian.net/archive/2008/04/09/paging-made-easy-in-ms-sql-server-2005.aspx

Comment: True djeeg, my only issue is on easiness to develop (to me it would be ok, but I cannot take true decision on technology) and performances. In fact I was thinking about using a third party tool like DevExpress to create a GridView that could be consumed by a website and inside SP too. Don't know if it is an optimal solution. What do you think?

Comment: On the other hand to get paging and progressive fetching it is needed an extra coding, isn't it?

Comment: SPGridViews can be very complicated (read "painful") to work with but you can usually get them to do exactly what you want. If possible, I wouldn't reinvent the wheel if a vendor webpart meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used the Telerik SPRadGrid web part (for SP 2010) which enables completely declarative binding to SP2010 SQL backend. You may give it a spin on their demo site here: http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Pages/default.aspx. It also supports SP lists binding from design-time and I heard that they have Excel binding in the works and it will be released with their next major installment.